# How to remove a high accuracy numerical number from a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

My numerical calculation gives a list of numbers

`list = {-0.36, 0.2499999999999992, -0.21, 0.36, 0.36}`,

I want to delete `0.25` which appears as `0.2499999999999992` in the list due to the numerical process. How can I remove such a number? I tried

`DeleteCases[Chop@list, {0.25}]`

but did not work.

Comment: It's not really "highly accurate" so much as not showing a more desired value. Do you want to remove it entirely, or just replace it with 0.25?

Comment: What do you want to happen if the list also contains `0.25` or other numbers such as `0.149999999999992`? For example, what is the desired output of  `list2 = {-0.36, 0.2499999999999992, -0.21, 0.36, 0.36, 0.25, 0.149999999999992}`?

Comment: @user1066, I want to remove all numerical numbers that are almost `0.25`  e.x `0.2499999999999991`, `0.2499999999999992`, or exactly `0.25`. It would be nice also if the new list `list2` also showed only a few significant numbers say 4 such that `0.149999999999992` becomes `0.15`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, remove it entirely

Comment: I think you are Making A Mistake. It is not _accuracy_ that you are removing — the extra digits is a consequence of how floating-point numbers work. In other words, **you are arbitrarily tossing data from your list**. Most likely the correct way of handling this is simply filtering the numbers by rounding to a certain _precision_ (such as to hundredths), _but only for display_. Care must be taken that this rounding pass does not propagate elsewhere or you will introduce bias into your dataset!

Comment: One typically does this using a numeric comparison and a threshold. Here are a couple of variants. `In[226]:= list = {-0.36, 0.2499999999999992, -0.21, 0.36, 0.36};
DeleteCases[list, vv_ /; Abs[vv - 1/4] < 1/1000]

Out[227]= {-0.36, -0.21, 0.36, 0.36}

In[229]:= ResourceFunction["Discard"][list, Abs[# - 1/4] < 1/1000 &]

Out[229]= {-0.36, -0.21, 0.36, 0.36}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not very elegant, but since you explicitly mention that you want to remove `0.2499999999999992`

```
list /. (0.2499999999999992 -> Nothing)
```

or if you want to delete `0.25` explicitly

```
Round[list, 0.01] /. (0.25 -> Nothing)
```

and get

> `{-0.36, -0.21, 0.36, 0.36}`

Answer (score 6):

```
list = {-0.36, 0.2499999999999992, -0.21, 0.36, 0.36}

Delete[list, 
 Position[Round[list, 0.01] - list, Except[0.], {1, ∞}, 
  Heads -> False]]
```

> {-0.36, -0.21, 0.36, 0.36}

---

*Note*

It has the same accuracy and precision as other numbers in the list.

```
Accuracy /@ list
Precision /@ list
```

> {16.3983, 16.5566, 16.6324, 16.3983, 16.3983} {MachinePrecision,
> MachinePrecision, MachinePrecision, \ MachinePrecision,
> MachinePrecision}

Comment: It's a (+1) from me of course, just a comment: you can forget `Heads -> False` and just use `// List` at the end. Very minor comment actually

Answer (score 3):

Using `Cases` and `FractionalPart`:

```
Cases[If[Abs[#] < 1, FractionalPart[#], #] & /@ list, x_ /; x != 0.25]

(*{-0.36, -0.21, 0.36, 0.36}*)
```

Or using `Select`:

```
Select[If[Abs[#] < 1, FractionalPart[#], #] & /@ list, # != 0.25 &]

(*{-0.36, -0.21, 0.36, 0.36}*)
```

Or using `DeleteCases`:

```
DeleteCases[list, x_ /; x == 0.25]

(*{-0.36, -0.21, 0.36, 0.36}*)
```

Or using `ReplaceAll`:

```
list /. x_ /; x == 0.25 :> Nothing

(*{-0.36, -0.21, 0.36, 0.36}*)
```